# Necessary and sufficient condition for being a covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose I have a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous, $X$ is compact, connected and also $f$ is a local homeomorphism, what condition should we include in $X$ so that $f$ becomes a covering map? Am I making any sense?

Comment: You should probably assume that it is surjective. :) Connectedness of $X$ is not needed. The definition can be found on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_map.

Comment: @mex you should list the definition of the covering map or give us a link in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, then compactness of $X$ and surjectivity of $f: X\to Y$ are already sufficient conditions for $f$ to be a covering map (*edit:* just to be clear, this is in addition to $f$ being a local homeomorphism). See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45990/when-is-a-local-homeomorphism-a-covering-map/45999#45999).

Note that $f$ is necessarily surjective if $Y$ is assumed to be connected, because $f$ is closed and open (still under the hypothesis that $Y$ is Hausdorff).

Comment: Surely $f$ must also be a local homeomorphism?

Comment: @Jacob: This was assumed in the OP's question

Comment: @JacobSchlather: You are right, of course. I (implicitely) meant in addition to $f$ being a local homeomorphism. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @JuanS It was unclear to me, because the OP was already assuming that X was compact as well.