# Do local diffeomorphisms preserve homotopy class?

Tags: homotopy-theory

The problem that I am working on says to either prove or disprove that there is a smooth map f : $S^3$ to $S^1$x$S^2$ such that the differential is an isomorphism at each point.

It seems like the easiest way would be to say that $S^3$ is simply connected, hence no such f exists, but I cannot figure out whether this works or not.

For reference, the closest thing I could find is the fact that local diffeomorphisms from compact manifolds are a stable homotopy type, which (I think) is something different from preserving homotopy class. Well-known theorems are considered fair game - the problem is from a recent qualifying exam (UMD Topology, August 2018).

Comment: A proper local diffeomorphism is a covering map.

Comment: I think that map can't exist, and to prove it I would use the fact that @MichaelAlbanese stated, and use higher homotopy groups. E.g, check page 339 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology for help with homotopy groups of spheres. Again, I haven't thought about it much, but I suspect they are not locally diffeomorphic (I have some reasonable geometric reasons), and that would be my approach to prove I'm right.

Comment: Another approach would be de Rham cohomology.

Comment: How about this? If they were locally diffeomorphic, then subtracting a point in both cases would give us a local diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^2$ minus a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a manifold $X$, there *always* exists a simply connected manifold $\tilde{X}$ and a local diffeomorphism $\tilde{X} \to X$: it's the universal cover of $X$. In this case, $\mathbb{R} \times S^2$. So this approach won't work.

Here's something that will. A continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is proper. So the purported local diffeomorphism $f : S^3 \to S^1 \times S^2$ would be proper. [A proper local homeomorphism is a covering map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/860351/10014) So $f$ would be a covering map. Since $S^3$ is simply connected, it should be the universal cover. But the universal cover of $S^1 \times S^2$ is actually $\mathbb{R} \times S^2$. So we reach a contradiction.