# Nonzero Jacobian implies diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Suppose $f: U\to V$ is a $C^1$ surjection from a $k$ dimensional manifold $U$ onto a $k$ dimensional simply connected manifold $V$ with everywhere nonzero Jacobian or nonsingular differential. Is $f$ diffeomorphic?

Comment: If $U$ is compact, then Stack of Records Theorem gives that $f$ is a covering map. So... maybe?

Comment: @Prototank: The stack of records theorem implies local not global diffeomorphism. The map bijective map $[0,1)\to S^1$ satisfies the stack of records theorem, yet it is not a global diffeomorphism.

Comment: According to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860351/a-proper-local-diffeomorphism-between-manifolds-is-a-covering-map, if $f$ is proper, it's a covering map.  So, in this case $f$ is a diffeomorphism (assuming $U$ is connected).  In particular, this applies if $U$ is a closed manifold.  Thus, a counterexample must have $U$ non-compact.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I do not see how the covering map leads to diffeomorphism for connected $U$. How do you explain the map $x\in [0,1]\to (\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$ being not diffeomorphic?

Comment: Well, first, I was assuming $U$ and $V$ have no boundary.  Second, if you extend the domain to be $(-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$ for any finite $\epsilon > 0$, then this map is not proper (and it is not a covering no matter what you do with the domain, unless you make the domain all of $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The smooth mapping from $S^1$ to a figure $8$ loop has both $U$ and $V$ without boundary. It satisfies the theorem you cited, with the map being proper and covering. Yet it is not a diffeomorphism. Aside from this example, I just do not see how that theorem, particularly covering map, helps with the problem. Second, why do I need to extend the domain for my original example $U=[0,1]$? That example satisfies the theorem you cited.

Comment: @Hans:  The figure 8 loop isn't a manifold and it's not simply connected.  What does it mean to "satisfy a theorem"?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: You are right that figure $8$ is not a manifold. My bad. I see your point to extend the interval so as to include the boundary. Can you explicate why you say the map for the extended $(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ is not proper? It seems the preimage of a compact subset of the circle is compact in the interval, and thus the map is proper. By satisfying "a theorem" I mean it satisfies the premise of the theorem and therefore its conclusion. I am looking into Moishe Cohen's answer.

Comment: The map is not proper because $K = S^1$ is a compact subset of $S^1$, but $f^{-1}(K) = (-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$ is not compact.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Oh darn. I was focusing on the compact proper subsets of $S^1$. Thanks. So then, how does covering map lead to injectiveness and thus diffeomorphism?

Comment: This comes from general results about covering spaces.  Namely, given a (nice enough) connected space $X$ with basepoint $x_0 \in X$, to each subgroup $H\subseteq \pi_1(X,x_0)$ there is a unique connected covering space $X_H\xrightarrow{\pi_H} X$ with basepoint $x_h$ (with $\pi(x_h) = x_0)$ for which $\pi_\ast(\pi_1(X_H, x_0')) = H$.  Now, if $X$ is simply connected, i.e., $\pi_1(X,x_0) = \{1\}$, then the only possibility for $H$ is $H = \{1\}$.  So, there is a unique connected covering of $X$.  Since the identity map $X\rightarrow X$ is a covering, this must be the only one....

Comment: In summary, if $V$ is simply connected, the only connected covering it has is itself.  So, if $U\rightarrow V$ is a covering, it must be the case that $U\cong V$.