# Submersion map from $S^2$ to $S^2$ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

If $f:S^2\mapsto S^2$ be a submersion. Show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

I got that $f$ is surjective using $S^2$ is connected and compact.(Theorem :  If $X$ is compact and $Y$ is connected, then every submersion $f:X→Y$ is surjective)

Comment: Do you know any results about proper submersions?

Answer (score 3):

To say that $f:S^2\to S^2$ is a submersion means that at any $s\in S$ the tangent map $T_sf:T_sS^2\to T_sS^2$ is surjective, hence bijective since source and target of that linear map have same dimension (namely 2).
We deduce that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.
But [a local diffeomorphism (or even local homeomorphism) with compact source is a covering space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/45999/3217), so that $f$ is actually a differentiable covering map.
And now for the *coup de grâce*: since $S^2$ is simply connected a connected covering map must be one sheeted, so that $f$ is a bijective local diffeomorphism.
Its inverse $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable (by some avatar of the implicit function theorem), and finally we can proudly assert:
**Yes, $f$ is a diffeomorphism.**

Comment: I read it like a musical! I’d give you +2 if I could :)

Comment: Thank you, @Son, this is quite flattering. Especially since anyone who heard me sing would run for his life :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GeorgesElencwajg