Surjective, closed local homeomorphism with finite fibers is a covering map?
Let $E,X$ be connected, locally path connected topological spaces and $\pi: E \to X$ a surjective, closed local homeomorphism with finite fibers. Is $\pi$ necessarily a covering map?
I know that this is true when $E$ is Hausdorff (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45999), but what happens if we don't assume $E$ to be Hausdorff?
My intuition tells me that this isn't true, but I have no idea how to construct a counterexample.
Note: a continuous closed map with compact fibers is necessarily a proper map. However, a proper map $f: X \to Y$ is not necessarily closed, without additional assumptions on $Y$ (e.g. Hausdorff and compactly generated). This is why I formulated my question in this way.

A better question is what is the motivation for considering covering maps in the context of non-Hausdorff spaces.

@MoisheKohan That's a fair point, I agree, perhaps I should have included that. There is an answer already, but in short, I'm trying to understand why a certain proof can't work, and a negative answer to this question would give an explicit example where the proof fails.

Here's a counterexample: Let $E$ be the line with two origins, i.e. $E = (\mathbb{R}_1 \sqcup \mathbb{R}_2) / {{\sim}}$ where $\sim$ identifies each point of $\mathbb{R}_1 \setminus \{0\}$ with the corresponding point of $\mathbb{R}_2 \setminus \{0\}$ (here the subscripts are just to distinguish one copy of $\mathbb{R}$ from the other).
The projection map $\pi\colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, surjective, closed, and a local homeomorphism, but it is obviously not a covering map: $|\pi^{-1}(0)| = 2$ whereas $|\pi^{-1}(x)| = 1$ for all $x \neq 0$.
